# Grabbing specific, non-specific occurrances of a string with RegEx

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex

So, I am writing a C# WinForms application to grab images from 4chan.
Recently, the images have been hosted on another domain, so I have been attempting to use RegEx to scan the html code of a thread from the `boards.4chan.org` domain, and using it to find the corresponding image on the `i.4cdn.org` domain where they are now stored. I'm doing it this way so that I can download single threads instead of the entire board.

```
private void DownloadImages(string saveDir, string board, string threadNum, string fileType)
{  
    string htmlString;
    int imageNum = 0;  
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    try  
    {
        htmlString = wc.DownloadString("http://boards.4chan.org/" + board + "/res/" + threadNum);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = ex.ToString();
        return;
    }
    txtOutput.Text = "Found thread!";

    MatchCollection allMatchResults;
    Regex regexObj = new Regex("//i.4cdn.org/" + board + "/src/*." + fileType,RegexOptions.Singleline);
    allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(htmlString);

    foreach(Match match in allMatchResults)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = match.ToString();

        try
        {
            //txtOutput.Text = "Downloading file ";
            wc.DownloadFile("http:" + match.Value.ToString() + "." + fileType, saveDir + imageNum + "." + fileType);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            imageNum++;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = x.ToString();
            return;
        }        
    }
}
```

Now, I haven't used RegEx in a while, nor have I used it with C# in the past, so I'm not sure if what I'm doing it entirely wrong or not. I'm trying to have it parse the `htmlString` for any matches to `//i.4cdn.org` url, with the board and filetype being passed though (they are from checkedListBoxes on the form, for specificity).

I have it grab the source of the webpage into a string so that I can parse through it and look for the image urls, which would then allow me to find the corresponding image(s) on the 4cdn domain.

My problem is that although I get the message "Found Thread" as I should, the program never seems to advance beyond that point - it appears to never enter the `foreach` loop.

If there is a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions. I have read not to try parsing html with RegEx.. but I assumed that I would be fine here since it isn't the html itself I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual regex means this :

[image: Regular expression visualization]

So use this regex instead:

```
new Regex("//i.4cdn.org/" + board + "/src/[^.]+\\." + fileType, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

which means

[image: Regular expression visualization]